# Github OAuth Provider - Get username or id

Tags: github, oauth, firebase-authentication, github-api

I'm using the Firebase Authentication services to authenticate users using Github as the provider. The OAuth response returns the access-token for the user along with some other information (e.g. email, name...). For persistence-purposes I need to save the authenticated users **username** or **id**, but I can't seem to find that information in the OAuth callback.

Am I missing something or is the user data just not provided using OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear which SDK you are using but Firebase auth returns additionalUserInfo form OAuth providers. For example, with the JS SDK, you can get the [additionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#.AdditionalUserInfo) as follows:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider())
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.username);
    console.log(reuslt.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

Comment: Yes, they did provide additionalUserInfo when I added "user" to the scope e.g. new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider().addScope("user");

Comment: Is that a question or a confirmation of my answer? They will return basic profile additional user info without any additional scope.

Comment: That's true, although not sure if you're getting the username without defining the scope (could be wrong). Anyways, this is basically the answer, so I'll mark it as the correct one